# Question about joint cdf

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

we have that
$P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = \int \int_{s \leq x, t \leq y} f_{X,Y}(s,t) dsdt$

But how would for example

$P(X \leq x, Y \geq y)$
Be defined?

Would it just be:

$P(X \leq x, Y \geq y) = \int \int_{s \leq x, t \geq y} f_{X,Y}(s,t) dsdt$
?

I am not 100% sure if I remember correctly, but I remember seeing a formula like that somewhere:
Would

$P ( Y \geq y) = P(X \geq x) + P(X \leq x,  Y \geq y) $

hold in general? Or should there be any specific conditions on the random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The beginning equation is unfortunately wrong already, it should be $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = \iint_{s \leq x, t \leq y}f_{X, Y}(s, t)ds dt$.  You obviously confused the integrating variables with $x, y$ in the event.

Comment: By definition, the chance of any event $\mathcal E$ is the integral over $\mathcal E$ of the density.  There's no need for any additional definitions.  Your last equation, although incorrect, is reminiscent of formulas like $\Pr(x_1\lt X\le x_2,\ y_1\lt Y\le y_2)=F(x_2,y_2)-F(x_1,y_2)-F(x_2,y_1)+F(x_1,y_1)$ where $F(x,y)=\Pr(X\le x,\ Y\le y)$ is the CDF. These arise by adding and subtracting rectangular regions.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: thank you. I got mixed up with s,x,t, corrected it in both equations

Comment: @whuber: thank you very much. Then that must be it, I had the $F(x_i, y_j)$ formulas in mind when trying to remember the formula I was looking for